# How can CsvHelper be configured to ignore a footer row that differs from the data rows?

Tags: csvhelper

I have a CSV file with a record count row at the end

```
id|key|limit
123|1|591
456|2|921
record_count|2
```

When I run this with `CsvHelper` using a class map it throws an exception when it gets to the `record_count|2` row. I'm working around it by configuring a `ReadingExceptionOccurred` handler to ignore that row.

```cs
csvConfig.ReadingExceptionOccurred = ex =>
{
    if (ex.Exception.Context.Parser.RawRecord.Contains("record_count"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

This works but is there is a more "standard" method for handling this footer record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ShouldSkipRecord` in the configuration.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = "|",
        ShouldSkipRecord = args => args.Record[0] == "record_count"
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("id|key|limit\n123|1|591\n456|2|921\nrecord_count|2"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {      
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int key { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I was just debugging a failing test related this issue when your answer arrived. How did you know? This solution works perfectly!